# Android Studio gradle 2.0 build successful, but toast error

Tags: android-studio-2.0

`Android studio` update to 2.0 toast the below error

[image]

I don't know why!

Comment: Where is your code regarding the Toast?

Comment: I'm having the same problem now. I don't know exactly what is happening but it seems to be counting every line printed to Standard Error as an error and proguard is spitting out warnings to it.

I didn't have this problem with AS 2.1.1 when my project still used android plugin 1.3 but as soon as i upgraded to plugin 2.1.0 it started.

What plugin version are you using?